# jquery ui dialog doesn't work with buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, confirmation

I'm trying to show a modal confirm dialog on delete link in a list action of a mvc 3 application.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 180
    });

});

    $(document).delegate(".deleteLink", "click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('#dialog-confirm')
   .dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal: true,
       resizable: false,
       height: 180,
       buttons: {
           'button text': function () {
               alert("button"); //this is the button, do something with it :)
           }
       }



});

    $dialog.dialog('open');

});
```

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete the item?" > 
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This item will be deleted. Are you sure?</p>
```

and this is the link

```
                        @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", "Need", new { id = item.NeedID }, new { @class = "deleteLink", title = "حذف" })
```

when i remove the buttons option it works but when i add it , it doesn't show up anymore
where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: at first i used the .live option but it was the same

Comment: Hi, I am trying to work on same. Did that work for you? Please I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

At a very quick glance - it would seem that buttons is an array.  Try pasting in the sample from the documentation:

```
    ... {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        height: 180,
        buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
   }
```